# ArcGIS 9.3 geoprocessing service output consideration

Tags: python, arcgis-server, javascript, geoprocessing, arcgis-9.3

I'm developing geoprocessing service which do few processes with geographic data. I would like to get somehow geometry of those data and use it in my web aplication (JS ArcGIS API). Now I'm wondering how to (with best performance) return geometry from service to my application?
Now I'm trying manually access to feature geometry, and while iterating throught it I'm concatenate it's coordinates to string. 
It is very slow method, because I've got about 60-90k vertex (avg) on polygon so concatenating it is taking to much of time. 
Can anyone see other possibilities to return geometry of features from service to JS with better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So is there a reason why you are trying to return the coordinates as a string instead of returning the data as is?  The output of your geoprocessing tasks should be returned as features without issue.  Can you simplify the polygon features so you do not have so many vertices.

This is a link to esri's general performance tips, it is down near the bottom concerning lines and polygons:

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/dotnet/index.htm#geoprocessing/an_ove-2102662086.htm